# Imagemagick create rectangles

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to create rectangles like this:[image]

I tried following command:

```
convert -size 720x567 xc:black -stroke white -strokewidth 5 -draw "rectangle 100,200 300,350 " -draw "rectangle 65,55 45,95 " -draw "rectangle 80,55 90,95 " -draw "rectangle 95,55 105,95 " -draw "rectangle 110,55 120,95 " -draw "rectangle 125,55 135,50 " test.png
```

and it created me this:

[image]

Any tips of how to achieve this

I tried Mark Setchell suggestion:

```
convert -size 720x567 xc:black -stroke blue -strokewidth 5 \
   -draw "rectangle 50,300 230,450"                        \
   -draw "rectangle 250,300 430,450"                       \
   -draw "rectangle 450,300 630,450" test.png
```

But I get this :

[image]

Comment: What you get if you use like this. `convert -size 720x567 xc:black test.png`

Comment: @Virb a black image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you expect to get blue boxes with a white stroke? I think you want something more like this:

```
convert -size 720x567 xc:black -stroke blue -strokewidth 5 \
   -draw "rectangle 50,300 230,450"                        \
   -draw "rectangle 250,300 430,450"                       \
   -draw "rectangle 450,300 630,450" test.png
```

[image]

Comment: hi my image looks different when I post your command, I post it inmy question.

Comment: Well, I can vouch for my image being what my code creates, so I would have to suspect your installation. Sorry to say, but I suggest you reinstall - what platform are you on?

Comment: I am working on windows, I will try it out with other options and give you a reply later. What I observed so far it that the image gets skewed if the strokewidth is greater than 1. If I run your command with a strokewidth of 1 it looks fine but the borders are thin.

Comment: I finally did it I downgraded my version to 6.9.3-7 and it worked, earlier I had7.0.2, you may add to your answer that it is a version issue so it becomes more clear to other

Answer (score 0):

For ImageMagick 7.0.x.x, your command should start with magick and not convert. So it would be:

```
magick -size 720x567 xc:black -stroke blue -strokewidth 5 \
   -draw "rectangle 50,300 230,450"                        \
   -draw "rectangle 250,300 430,450"                       \
   -draw "rectangle 450,300 630,450" test.png
```

[image]

You do not need to use multiple -draw commands. You can concatenate all the rectangle specifications in one -draw.

```
magick -size 720x567 xc:black -stroke blue -strokewidth 5 \
   -draw "rectangle 50,300 230,450 \
          rectangle 250,300 430,450 \
          rectangle 450,300 630,450" test2.png
```

[image]